# Image Magnifying Glass + mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, zooming

I'm currently experimenting with the following:

I have a map (as image). When hovering over specific countries, those countries get a big black border (this is realised with [maphilight.js](https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight)).

Now I want an extra. As some countries are very small on the map, I'd love to add a magnifying glass, so you can see the countries better.

Therefore, I found [okzoom](https://github.com/okfocus/okzoom) to be a very cool plugin which is easy to use and is working fine.

So I'm calling the function

```
$('#Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2017-08-25-161100-img').okzoom({
             width: 400,
            height: 400,
        scaleWidth:4000
            });
```

To add the magnifying glass, which is (as I said) working fine. The problem: This magnifying glass removes my functionality of the imagemap (not only the black border, but the complete imagemap functionality, as my mouse is completely removed.

The question now is: Is there any way to have both, a moving mouse, which clickable countries with the black borders when hovering over a country + the magnifying glass once hovering on the image? Is there any way to get the mouse visible underneath the magnifying glass with the used plugin? Is there another way (another plugin) to realise that zooming in but still have the image-map functionalities?

I also looked at the code of the plugin, and on some places (`touchstart`,etc.) it says `e.preventDefault()`, when I comment these lines, my hovering (the image map) is working again, but the magnifying glass is not working any more.

Any ideas?